# Would SQL Server 2012 SP4 break encryption?

Tags: sql-server

[SQL Server 2012 SP4](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2755533/how-to-obtain-the-latest-service-pack-for-sql-server-2012) was installed on a SQL Server 2012 machine running on Windows Server 2012 R2.

Afterward, the only table with encrypted columns could not be accessed. I get the following error:

> Please create a master key in the database or open the master key in the session

It is my understanding that this error most often shows when restoring to another server.  As far as I know, that didn't happen here.

I have tried the standard [fix](http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2010/03/resolving-please-create-master-key-in.html) on the off chance it would help. It didn't, but I get an error:

> An error occurred during service master key decryption

Researching that turned up nothing of use as it's not happening with linked servers.

I have also tried to REGENERATE the master key. Also no good.

The only change on the server was installing SP4. None of my searching has turned up anything so I wanted to ask others if they have seen or heard of this.

Comment: Its very, very, very unlikely that a SP release of SQL Server would have such a bug. I made a Google search about that and I found no mentions about such problem in the month since it was released, and a problem like that would be noticed for sure and would cause a big brouhaha. I think that this is a red herring, I would search other possible causes for your problem.

Comment: Assuming you have backed up your encryption keys, just restore them.

Comment: @Alex I did, and I put them in a "safe place" now I can't find them.